# facebook apprequests dialog error “An error occurred. Please try again later.”

Tags: facebook, invite, facebook-app-requests

I was searching all possible topics but now solution works for me.

There is my code, which works in all browsers except Chrome. There is just window with  `An error occurred. Please try again later.`.

It is identical code from FB documentation.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : {$appId},
    frictionlessRequests: true
  });

  function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
      message: '{_"FACEBOOK_INVITE_WINDOW_MESSAGE"}'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    //callback code
  }
</script>

<a onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;">
```

Comment: Try setting the `show_error` parameter to true in your dialog call, maybe that’ll give you some relevant info about the actual error. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: The error is 
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

It is used at 2 pages and works if FF, Opera, Safari. In Chrome works only at 1 page. Only sometimes it works at both pages in Chrome. So it cannot be thanks to redirect URL.

Answer (score 2):

This might be because your application is still in sandbox mode.

Comment: I think this would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the display option for the dialog ('popup, 'iframe'...)

For example:

```
FB.init({
  appId  : {$appId},
  frictionlessRequests: true,
  display: 'popup'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated if your application is on Facebook or not. The reason this is important is because of the `canvas_url` parameter of your application settings. If you **are** on `apps.facebook.com/app_namespace`, then you'll already have this field filled out. However some projects simply do not operate on Facebook itself. In such cases people don't really "need" to fill in this parameter. It is however necessary for app requests to work.

When a user acts on an application request (IE accepts it), they are redirected to the canvas url of that application. Not specifying the canvas url can nullify the request. This might also be the reason for the error.

Try setting your canvas url. You can even have it redirect to your proper URL, it doesn't have to "do" anything else.